# Angularjs directive parses controllers collection

Tags: angularjs

Working on pager directive in angularjs. When I hard code sample collection ($scope.installations) everything is OK, but when I pull data from server 'options' property in directive is always 'undefined'.

Here is my directive:

```
angular.module("qusion.ui.pager", [])
    .directive("qnPager", [
        function() {
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                    var options = scope.$eval(attrs.qnPager);
                    var settings = {
                        source: null,
                        paging: null,
                        schema: {
                            page: 'PageNumber',
                            size: 'Size',
                            totalPages: 'TotalPages',
                            totalCount: 'TotalCount'
                        }
                    };

                    angular.extend(settings, options);


                    scope.$watch(settings.source, function(value) {
                        console.log(settings.source); // UNDEFINED ???
                    });

                }
            };
        }
    ]);
```

Here is how I am calling it.

```
<ul qn:pager="{source: installations}">
```

And finally my controller sample

```
function MyController(Installation){
   $scope.installations = [];
   // get sample (this works)
   // $scope.installations = [{ID: 1, Title: 'Test 1'}, {ID: 2, Title: 'Test 2'}]
   // get from server (this don't work)
   Installation.getAll().then(function(data) {
       $scope.installations = data.Installations;
   });

}
```

Comment: Can you share you 'Installation' service code?

Comment: There are more dependencies behind so it will be a lot of code to paste here. It is just http request returning promise. This part works ok since table in template is filled with installation data.

Comment: The data you fill using async or sync request?

Comment: Async. Installation.getAll() returns promise. I am using $scope.installations to fill table and works fine.

Comment: It's possible to use isolate scope in your directive? Have you try scope { source : '=installations' } instead?

Answer (score 0):

See if this solves your problem:

Instead of assigning a new data array to installation -- i.e., instead of `$scope.installations = data.Installations;` -- try populating the same array. When you assign a new data array to installations, you may be losing the bindings to the old array -- i.e., the directive may still be bound to the previous data array.

```
$scope.installations.length = 0
for(var i = 0; i < data.Installations.length; i++){
    $scope.installations.push(data.Installations[i]);
}
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/12287364/215945 for more info.

**Update:** [angular.copy()](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.copy) can/should be used instead:

```
angular.copy(data.Installations, $scope.installations);
```

When a destination is supplied to the copy() method, it will first delete destination's elements, and then copy in the new ones from source.