# How to make Angular JS wait for $scope variable to be set before triggering ng-style

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ng-style

**Summary of the Problem:** I want to dynamically apply a CSS style to several `div`'s using Angular JS'
s `ng-style` directive. The trouble is that the expression bound to `ng-style` depends on a specific scope variable that I use to define the style I want to return. But here’s the catch: this scope variable is not set initially. It is only set after a particular event handler fires, so I need to make `ng-style` wait for this scope variable to be set before firing.

**Background:** I'm using Angular JS v.1.7.8

**My Code:**

```
<!-- index.html -->
<div ng-app='myApp'>
    <div ng-controller='myCtrl as ctrl'>
        <div ng-style='clientScope.ctrl.getStyle()'></div>
        <div ng-style='clientScope.ctrl.getStyle()'></div>
        <div ng-style='clientScope.ctrl.getStyle()'></div>
        <div ng-style='clientScope.ctrl.getStyle()'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
// app.js
(function(){
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('myApp', [])
        .controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
            var ctrl = this;

            ctrl.colorInScope = function() {
                if ($scope.colors) { return true; };
                return false;
            }

            ctrl.getStyles = function() {
                return {'color': $scope.colors['myColor'] };
            }

         /* Note I'm not actually using setTimeout() in my real
            setMyColor function, but am just using it here as an
            easy way to simulate to delayed nature of how myColor gets set. */

            function setMyColor() {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $scope.colors = {};
                    $scope.colors['myColor'] = '#7e9cee';
                }, 3000);
            }

            setMyColor();

        });

}());
```

Currently, `ng-style`'s expression is evaluated as soon as the `div` it is bound to loads, which happens before `setMyColor` is ever called. As a result, `$scope.colors` in `ctrl.getStyles` is `undefined` and Javascript throws this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'myColor' of `undefined`

**What I've tried so far:**

I see two possible approaches to fixing this:

1) Prevent `ng-style`'s expression from being evaluted before `$scope.colors["myColor"]` is set.

*Note:* I've already looked into two Angular JS directives (`ng-if` and `ng-show`) that do something similar, but they ultimiately did not achieve what I want. Here's why:

- `ng-if="expression"` removes the element it is bound to from the DOM if `expression` evaluates to `false`,
  thus the element is only included in the DOM if `expression` is `true`. I tried attaching `ng-if="clientScope.ctrl.colorInScope()"` to my `div`'s' like so:

  ```
  <div ng-if="clientScope.ctrl.colorInScope()" ng- 
  style="clientScope.ctrl.getStyle()"></div>
  .
  .
  .
  <div ng-if="clientScope.ctrl.colorInScope()" ng- 
  style="clientScope.ctrl.getStyle()"></div>
  ```

  but this immediately removed the `div`'s from the DOM upon the DOM's initial loading because `clientScope.ctrl.colorInScope` does not evaluate to `true` at that point.
- `ng-show="expression"` applies the `visibility: hidden` style to the element it is bound to if `expression` evalutes to `false`, thus the element is only visable if `expression` is true. I also tried attaching `ng-show="clientScope.ctrl.colorInScope()"` to my `div`'s but even though my `div`'s visibility was initially hidden, `ng-style` was evaluated prematurely anyways and Javascript threw an error because `$scope.colors` was `undefined`.

2) Have some sort of method in `ctrl.getStyles` to pause the execution of the function until `$scope.colors["myColor"]` is set. *Note:* I do not want to use a timer in `ctrl.getStyles` because then the function would wait every time it is called. Basically I want the function
to pause if `$scope.colors["myColor"]` is `undefined` (and wait for it's value to be set) or proceed straight away if `$scope.colors["myColor"]` has a value.

I've read a little bit about `$scope.$watch`, which is basically an Angular JS method for `$scope` that takes the name of a scope variable to watch and an event handler and triggers the event handler when the scope variable changes. I could potentially initialize `$scope.colors` to `0` at the start of my controller and then add `await $scope.$watch('colors', myHandler())` to `ctrl.getStyles = async () => ...` and return `{'color': $scope.colors["myColor"]}` from `myHandler` but this wouldn't work because `$scope.$watch` would only get triggered once (after `setMyColor` finishes) and Javascript would eventually throw some kind of timeout error or something because it would be waiting on `$scope.$watch` forever (although I'm not sure exactly what my program's behavior would be in this case because I'm still learning about how `async/await` work).

I've also read [Wait until scope variable is loaded before using it in the view in angular.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16617259/wait-until-scope-variable-is-loaded-before-using-it-in-the-view-in-angular-js) which was helpful in showing how to leverage `ng-show`, but it doesn't really answer my question about how to stall `ng-style`.

**Conclusion:**

Do any of you Angular JS experts out there know of a better solution for what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: `this wouldn't work because $scope.$watch would only get triggered once ` I don't think this is true. $scope.watch creates a watcher on a variable, it gets fired when it changes at every digest cycle. Why can't it be used to solve this problem?

if it's updating multiple values over time, you need be polling, then pushing updates to this variable thats watched. But if you're just waiting for it to be ready (1 time event) then this should work fine.

Comment: @someguy Doesn't `$scope.$watch` only fire when `colors` changes? And in this case `colors` would change only once (when `setMyColor` terminates).

Comment: Yes, it will only fire when colors changes. If `colors` is expected to change more than once overtime, you need some mechanism to fetch the updated colors over time as well. Then you can simply update colors, the $scope.watch will trigger everytime, and the style will be reevaluated.

Comment: @someguy It would work for the first `div` but not the rest because `$scope.$watch` would never fire in subsequent calls to `ctrl.getStyles` (because `colors` was changed once, and never gets changed again).

Comment: My suggested approach is to use `color` is a model for each of the divs. Assuming the same color. Set a default color, whatever.

If the event indeed only happens once, (isLoading) for example, then you can use a boolean and $scope.watch on that.

in the $scope.watch, set the updated color. ng-style should reevaluate.

Comment: @someguy can you provide some example code?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularjs-kgjuda

This example creates two paragraphs tied to the same model for a color. The color is updating every 3000 ms. The style gets reevaluated. 

If your problem isn't {how do I update the color after a specific event}, this won't help you.

If it is, you can replace the $interval, with a callback after your specific event. If your event is happening over time, put it in a interval.

Answer (score 1):

> Javascript throws this error:
>
> > TypeError: Cannot read property 'myColor' of undefined

To avoid the type error, check for the existence of the variable:

```
ctrl.getStyles = function() {
    if (!$scope.colors) return;
    //ELSE
    return {'color': $scope.colors['myColor'] };
}
```

This will avoid the type error.